# Can I skip attribute "type" in "style" tag in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, css, html

According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp), I can skip attribute `type` for tag `script` in HTML5.

**Evidence**:

> **Differences Between HTML 4.01 and HTML5**
>
> The "type" attribute is
>   required in HTML 4, but optional in HTML5.

Can I do exactly the same with `style` tag? [I was unable](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp) to find similar note. It only says

> type   *text/css*  Specifies the media type of the  tag

but no info about omitting it. I don't care about IE, Edge or that sort of crap from Microsoft. I would like to write as less unnecessary code as possible. Ideally I would like to use just:

```
<style>.foo { color: red; }</style>
```

Comment: I find W3Schools to be lacking, i would use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) and ofc [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/)

Comment: Google used to have the 'block a site from showing up in your search results'-feature, but I've since had to resort to plugins or extensions. And damn, is it worth it to block W3Schools.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the [**documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style):

> **type**
>
> This attribute defines the styling language as a MIME type (charset should not be specified). This attribute is **optional** and
> default to text/css if it's missing.

Also comparing **html 4.01** and **html 5**:

**html 4.01**

> **type = content-type [CI]**
>
> This attribute specifies the style sheet
> language of the element's contents and overrides the default style
> sheet language. The style sheet language is specified as a content
> type (e.g., "text/css"). **Authors must supply a value for this
> attribute**; there is no default value for this attribute.

[html 4.01 - The style element w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.2.3)

**html 5**

> The type attribute gives the styling language. If the attribute is
> present, its value must be a valid MIME type that designates a styling
> language. The charset parameter must not be specified. The default
> value for the type attribute, which is used if the attribute is
> absent, is "text/css".

[html 5 - The style element w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-style-element)

Comment: MDN documentation is third party, albeit better written than the W3Schools stuff, but it would be better to link to the W3C specification as that is as close to authoritative as we're likely to get.

Comment: @Quentin W3Schools is also third party. Having "W3" in your name doesn't make you a W3C authority, as much as W3Schools likes to think so.

Comment: @HugoZink Quantin comment means the same.

Comment: @slick Glad that I helped you.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can, according to the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-style-type):

> The type attribute gives the styling language. If the attribute is
>   present, its value must be a valid MIME type that designates a styling
>   language. The charset parameter must not be specified. The default
>   value for the type attribute, which is used if the attribute is
>   absent, is "text/css". [RFC2318]

The default value already is `text/css`.

Comment: Why are you linking to a three and a half year old editors draft instead of the current specification?

Comment: My fault, I corrected that.

Comment: That's not the spec, and [the homepage](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML) says that content is being migrated away from there. The spec is at http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/

Comment: You're completely right!

Comment: Thank you @KittMedia as well.