# What happens if I do not specify the MIME type for <style> in HTML?

Tags: html, mime-types

I am wondering if I use the style tag without MIME type while inclusion of CSS, what will happen?

Thank you,

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33210842/can-i-skip-attribute-type-in-style-tag-in-html5

Comment: Nothing (in modern browser, can`t say about netscape navigator).

Comment: Thank you @aggaton

Answer (score -2):

The type attribute specifies Internet Media Type or the content type of the  tag. Specifying type as text/css will indicate inclusion of css content.

Syntax:

However, not mentioning it will still give the same output. Hence, the style type need not be mentioned explicitly.

Sources:[1]: (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_type.asp)!

Comment: Thanks, but I need to improve the question I think.